# What has changed in nvidia proprietary driver packaging in 18.04 Bionic?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

For many years I have installed nvidia proprietary driver manually installing only 4 packages and everything works fine: nvidia-xxx, libcuda1, nvidia-opencl-icd and nvidia-settings

"sudo dpkg -i *.deb"... Simple like that.
I usually keep those 4 packages in case I get to have an X display problem when I experiment installing unstable things, so I can manually reinstall driver without having internet connection.

Now I use Kubuntu 18.04 alpha and I had nvidia proprietary driver installed from PPA working properly until yesterday (2018-03-02):
https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Yesterday (2018-03-02) with some updates, OpenGL had been broken. So I uninstalled nvidia driver from PPA to try install nvidia from official repositories. The surprise was that it tried to install a bunch of packages that I had never seen before in other versions of Ubuntu:
http://pasteall.org/854414

So, what has changed in nvidia proprietary packaging driver starting from 390 in Ubuntu 18.04? Could someone explain it? Is there any documentation about the changes? Why libnvidia-compute? Why xserver-xorg-video-nvidia? Why so many i386 packages? Documentation of the decision on packaging changes please.

With so many packages, apparently it will not be so easy to trubelshoting nvidia graphics problems when trying to solve it by installing packages manually, for example.

Comment: Excellent because I can't login because of an nvidia issue. I also do the same approach.

Comment: Something was definitely messed up with the Nvidia packages: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/+bug/1752053

Comment: I've installed Kubuntu 18.04 final, and the only problem I have at the moment is an inability to turn off the Nvidia GPU when I switch to Intel graphic (`sudo prime-select intel`). [A good discussion about it is here.](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1032482/optimus-on-ubuntu-18-04-is-a-step-backwards-investigating-other-distributions-/)

Comment: the new prime-select is really slow because it basically uninstalls the nvidia driver and rebuilds the initramfs every time you switch from nvidia to intel, so that it can reenable nouveau so that the nvidia card can be powered down by a kernel feature which only works with nouveau, rather than bbswitch (old way). This requires a reboot; the need to reboot in 17.10 was due to a logind bug, but reboot is no longer a workaround but a requirement. So it's slow, inconvenient and broken, with the best case being slow and inconvenient.
 I switched to Mint 18.3 with the hwe updates of ubuntu 17.10.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a ppa and don't install manually. Just enable the "restricted" and "universe" repositories and then install the drivers using apt:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-xxx libcuda1 nvidia-opencl-icd nvidia-settings
```

Replace "xxx" with the actual driver version.

For a list of available drivers, run  the following command:

```
apt-cache search nvidia | grep -P '^nvidia-'
```